# dynamically style DraftJS .DraftEditor-editorContainer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I need to dynamically style the draftjs editor container (basically I need to dynamically apply font sizes to the container, as the font sizes are in percentages). Normally, dynamic styling in react is done by applying styles to the component, but for draftJS, styling the component itself doesn't work and you need to use css to style the `.DraftEditor-editorContainer`class.

Is it possible to dynamically style the `.DraftEditor-editorContainer` while adhering to React principles? I could easily do the dynamic styling with jQuery, but from what I understand this is a horrible practice and should never be done. Is there no other way?

Comment: https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-inline-styles#mapping-a-style-string-to-css

Comment: This is for applying inline styles to the words within the .DraftEditor-editorContainer. I want to apply styles to the .DraftEditor-editorContainer itself.

Comment: how about https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/342